# Thread 1: "Duplicate plugin key: InAppWebViewFlutterPlugin"

Tags: flutter

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

I am getting `"Duplicate plugin key: InAppWebViewFlutterPlugin"` error on `AppDelegate`. However, I can't spot where to fix?

`Class InAppWebViewFlutterPlugin is implemented in both /Runner.app/Frameworks/flutter_inappwebview_quill.framework/flutter_inappwebview_quill (0x10483a600) and /Runner.app/Frameworks/flutter_inappwebview.framework/flutter_inappwebview (0x103a42600). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Duplicate plugin key: InAppWebViewFlutterPlugin'`

In this case, what do I have to do to avoid this error?

Comment: hello @chichi did solve this issue? I am getting this error also.

Comment: I had to remove `flutter_quill`. This one and some package that uses `in_app_web_view`are conflicting each other!